# How to extract the hyper links from a webpage in javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, html

As soon as the web page loading is completes and whenever the cursor will be clicked/hover on any hyper links in that web page, I want to extract that particular link on which my mouse clicked/hover. So what is the JavaScript code snippet for this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
document.onclick = function(e) {
    var target = e.srcElement;
    if (target != null) {
         var href = target.href;
         if (href != null) {
             alert("link extracted: " + href);
         }
    }
    return false;
};
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if($(e.target).closest('a').length){
        alert('You clicked a link');
        alert($(e.target).closest('a').attr('href'));
    }
    else{
        alert('You did not click a link');
    }
});
```